# C# Threading Object: Calling non-static threading object from static main()

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to call instances of threads from my main function. The threads called are overriden function from my abstact class Running. However I run into the problem that I cannot call non-static function from static functions. In C# main seems to be always a static function.

Code snippet:

```
public class Program
{


static void Main(string[] args)
    {




objectWriter = new WriterThread[ulMaxChannels];
    threadWriter = new Thread[ulMaxChannels];
    objectReader = new ReaderThread[ulMaxChannels];
    threadReader = new Thread[ulMaxChannels];

    objectReader[bChannelIndex] = new ReaderThread(Device, ref myParameters);
    threadReader[bChannelIndex] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(objectReader[bChannelIndex].RunTransfers));
    threadReader[bChannelIndex].Start();




public abstract class Running     // WorkerThread
{

    public void RunTransfers()
    {
    }
    protected abstract
       void TransferAsync
        (byte bPipe, byte[] bBuffer, UInt32 ulPacketSize, ref UInt32 ulBytesTransferred, ref NativeOverlapped oOverlapped);

}
}

public class ReaderThread : Running
{
    public ReaderThread(int Device, ref ReadWriteParameter Param)
:   base(d3xxDevice, ref Param)
    {
    }


    void TransferSync(byte bPipe, byte[] bBuffer, UInt32 ulPacketSize, ref UInt32 ulBytesTransferred)
    {

    }


    void TransferAsync(byte bPipe, byte[] bBuffer, UInt32 ulPacketSize, ref UInt32 ulBytesTransferred, ref NativeOverlapped oOverlapped)
    {

    }
}
```

I receive error when associating objectReader and thread reader (Calling non static members from static function.

I realizied that I had to create a Program Object:

```
Program p1 = new Program();
```

But then I had to add the p1 to objectreader etc:

```
p1.objectWriter = new WriterThread[ulMaxChannels];
    p1.threadWriter = new Thread[ulMaxChannels];
    p1.objectReader = new ReaderThread[ulMaxChannels];
    p1.threadReader = new Thread[ulMaxChannels];

    p1.objectReader[bChannelIndex] = new ReaderThread(Device, ref p1.myParameters);
    p1.threadReader[bChannelIndex] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(p1.objectReader[bChannelIndex].RunTransfers));
    p1.threadReader[bChannelIndex].Start();
```

First question: Is this safe?
Second question: Is there not a more handy way to get this working? Seems to me this is the hard way to get this working. Should I rather exclude the threadWriter and objectwriter into non-static function first?

Comment: Why use threads at all instead of eg `Task.Run`? If you want to post messages to a queue for processing use an ActionBlock<T>. If you want multiple threads to work on the messages set the DOP of the block to something greater than 1. If you want to implement a pipeline of concurrent processing steps check the other Dataflow classes, especially TransformMany.

Comment: The code for the Program class is very incomplete - where and how are all the variables declared?

Comment: What are you trying to do with that code? .NET offers classes that implement *multiple* paradigms - task-based concurrency with `Task` et al, dataflows and CSP with Dataflow, parallel computation with Parallel.For/Foreach. Even Channels nowadays as a more generic CSP approach - you get the read/write/storage semantics without the processing offered by Dataflow. Spans and Pipelines in .NET Core add low allocation communication and streaming